# Group by and order by mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `jt_model_files` ORDER by id DESC
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM `jt_model_files` GROUP BY file_id ORDER by id DESC
```

[image]

What i want to achieve is

[image]

What is the possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is always problematic, even if it is allowed, because the results are undefined.
For your sample data, you should `GROUP BY model_id, file_id` and get the max value of `id`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, model_id, file_id
FROM jt_model_files
GROUP BY model_id, file_id
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you sir. @forpas
This solved my problem <3